# Is there Out-of-the-box authentication for ASP.NET Dynamic Data websites?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dynamic-data

I'm developing my first Dynamic Data website and I need very simple authentication (basically, you have access to the application or not - there is no field or table level requirements).

I've found a number of articles about enabling authentication however these seems to focus on a more complex granular level of requirement.

Is there a very simple way of invoking simple authentication?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to enable "Authentication", the "more complex granular level of requirement" is enabled with "roles" which are optional.

Here is a good link to start:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Comment: Excellent!  I hoped it was something like this - it just wasn't spelled out in any of the samples or documentation I found.  Thanks.